# Is there a possibility to set parameters from outside before running KSQL scrips?

Tags: ksqldb

I have a created a KSQL script to perform stream-table join. In addition to join,I perform filters based on the stream. I have deployed(interactive/headless) and tested it.Is it possible to set filter criteria from outside/properties to enable to run with different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set filter criteria from outside/properties to enable to run with different configuration.

No it's not, but if you're deploying a SQL file to headless KSQL server you could do some pre-processing of the SQL file to intersperse it with your variable values.